# Can default repository of artifact configured as Nexus in docker?

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Our project enabled Cloud SDK Pipeline. Upon a pull request, the pr job from Pipeline was triggered, and it tried to build with artifacts downloaded from: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2. However some dependencies of the project are not available in that repo. We would expect to connect to Nexus repo by default, as all dependencies are available there. Is it possible to configure docker in that way?

> 12:46:45  [ERROR] Non-resolvable import POM: Could not find artifact
>   com.sap.sgs:security-patched-spring-boot-dependencies:pom:2.1.7.RELEASE-sap-06
>   in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) @ line 28, column 22
>
> 12:46:45  [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar is missing. @
>   line 183, column 19
>
> 12:46:45  [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar is missing.
>   @ line 187, column 19
>
> 12:46:45  [ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.version' for
>   org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar is missing. @
>   line 191, column 19

Answer (score 1):

You can configure this in own settings file as described in the [maven documentation](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html)

And then configure the settings file in the pipeline config as described in the [pipeline guide](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/configuration.md#mavenexecute).

Example Settings file

```
<settings>
<mirrors>
<mirror>
  <id>internal-repository</id>
  <name>Maven Repository Manager running on repo.mycompany.com</name>
  <url>http://repo.mycompany.com/proxy</url>
  <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
</mirror>
</mirrors>
</settings>
```

Sample pipeline config

```
mavenExecute:
  dockerImage: maven:3.6.1-jdk-8-alpine
  projectSettingsFile: "settings.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cx Server comes with a read-only download cache to boost build performance and reduce redundant downloads of dependencies. It is active by default and transparently injected into maven and npm builds. By default it uses maven central and the official npm registry for looking up and downloading dependencies.

To set up a custom maven or npm repository, e.g., a corporate nexus that also holds internal artifacts, you can use the attributes `mvn_repository_url` and `npm_repository_url` in `server.cfg` (make sure to stop, remove, and start the Cx Server after making the configuration change).

More information can be found in the Cx Server operations guide: https://github.com/SAP/devops-docker-cx-server/blob/master/docs/operations/cx-server-operations-guide.md#configuring-the-cx-server